# connection string to connect to ORACLE database from a COBOL program

Tags: oracle, connection-string, cobol

Is there connection string to connect to oracle database  from a microfocus cobol program using openesql without creating ODBC DSN.

Comment: @kevin. thanks for the answer. can you pls provide a sample program with connect statements, and I don't have entry for that database connection in tnsnames.ora and don't have edit permission.is it possible to connect without entry in tnsnames.ora?

Comment: I'm using micro focus net express 5

Answer (score 1):

Not a connection string.

What you have to do is compile with the directive `SQL(TARGETDB=ORACLEOCI)`

You can find out more here: [Oracle OCI Support](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx20books/dbesql.htm)